# how to swap one text field to another in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In above image enter from and to field then
click the arrow  it will change value in page
 from value is stored in to and to value is 
stored in from  want code for swap that text box value in html

Comment: Sorry i'm finding it very hard to understand your question, also `no above image` and since you have no source code I have nothing to work with. Please edit your question so I can understand, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

hard to understand your question but maybe this one you want .

```
<input type="text" id="f1">
<input type="text" id="f2">
<input type="button" id="b1" value="interchange">

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#id1").click(function(){
     var f1 = $("#f1").val();
      $("#f2").val(f1);
   })
})
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript">   its not working bro
  </script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#id1").click(function(){
     var f1 = $("#f1").val();
      $("#f2").val(f1);
   })
})

</head>
</script>
<body> 
<input type="text" id="f1">
<input type="text" id="f2">
<input type="button" id="id1" value="interchange">
</body>
</html>

Comment: you closed head inside the script tag check here now http://jsfiddle.net/dnpuzhtc/

Comment: I want one more help how to store profile pic and fetch the profile pic code for php